# Replace image in Word docx format

Tags: python, image, replace, docx

I'm attempting to replace an image in a Word 2019 .docx file using the following code in Python:

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
tpl = DocxTemplate("C:\\temp\\replace_picture_tpl.docx")
context = {}
tpl.replace_pic('Sample.png','C:\\temp\\NewImage.png')
tpl.render(context)
tpl.save("C:\\temp\\TestOutput.docx")
```

I get the error ValueError: Picture Sample.png not found in the docx template.  I created the document by inserting a random .png file into a blank Word document and saving it.  I have double checked and confirmed that it is a .docx file.  I then used the code above to attempt to change the picture, which didn't work.  I looked around online for a couple of days and haven't been able to find anything to help yet.  I've gone through the docxtpl templates and sample code and it seems like the code references a "descr" tag to locate 'Sample.png'. However when I view the replace_picture_tpl.docx XML file, the image doesn't have this tag. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this worked for me using docxtpl and a template I modified in MS Word:

Right click the image in MS Word, Select "View Alt Text":

[image]

Write "replace_me" as the Alt Text.  Save and close.

Then:

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

tpl = DocxTemplate("sometemplate.docx")
tpl.replace_pic("replace_me", "yourimage.png")
```

Definitely worked on MS Word for Mac 2022, Version 16.69 (23010700).

Answer (score 1):

This property in Python is the "description" in the template DOCX document.

Open the template in MS Word or LibreOffice, click by your image to replace, click right button and select properties. In the dialog window, find the "Description" field, and put your tag here. Screenshot from LibreOffice Writer.

[image]